# Google Map Points Not Apears in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps

I've got a problem with a Google map on a site.... The map has loads of points marked on it which are loaded from a xml.... and in Chrome and Firefox, works fine. But in IE the points dont apear... and dont show me any errors...

```
http://www.consorcioluiza.com.br/site/mapa.asp
```

and the xml

```
www.consorcioluiza.com.br/site/xml/onde-estamos/sp.xml
```

What is going on??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work at all for me (including Firefox). The XML is not well formed, which both FF3 and IE6 will tell you. It looks like an invalid character.

```
    XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
    Location: http://www.consorcioluiza.com.br/site/xml/onde-estamos/ba.xml
    Line Number 15, Column 32:  
            <Address>AV. TANCREDO NEVES, N 148</Address>
    --------------------------------------^
```

Comment: wow.. i have edited the XML, deleting the invalids characters and.. BAZINGA!.. this works on IE. I think the error is on my xml generator... so..